# Message files for Autoware.Auto

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a very basic question but I am only starting to learn about Autoware.Auto, ROS 2, and all this toolchain used by them. One of the basics things that I am trying to do is locate the Autoware.Auto .msg files and take a look at them. But after clone the repository, could not find them.

Can someone explain the process of how the framework creates/generates them?

Thanks,
Gus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366862/message-files-for-autoware.auto/) by [gmnvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/64525/gmnvh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What you're looking for may be https://gitlab.com/autowarefoundation/autoware.auto/autoware_auto_msgs.

You can't just get it by cloning.
You can get it by doing the following in "[How To Build](https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/installation.html#installation-and-development-how-to-build)".

```
ade$ vcs import < autoware.auto.$ROS_DISTRO.repos
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gmnvh](https://answers.ros.org/users/64525/gmnvh/) on 2020-12-07**:
Thanks very much! Two reasons I could not find the messages. First, I was looking at Autoware.Auto\AutowareAuto repo. I did not see that there is a different repo only for messages (Autoware.Auto\autoware_auto_msgs). And second, they are not .msg files but .idl files. I also did not know that messages could be specified in .idl files. Thanks for all!!